# prop types not working in react application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

I am trying to use proptypes for in my react-redux app, but it is not working, or I am doing something wrong. this is end of code example:

```
LoginPage.propTypes = {
     login_form: PropTypes.string
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return { loginPage: state.loginPage }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage);
```

login_form is boolean, and I intentionaly wrote PropType.string to see if it was working but it didn't give me any errors, this is probably because of redux connect,but I couldn't search anything about that. please anyone tell me what I am doing wrong :/ thanks.

Comment: did you import all the required modules ?

Comment: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';  only this, is there anything else ?

Comment: I am saying that I pass boolean, login_form is true or false, in render I am using it to show or hide some views.

Comment: How are you saying login_form is Boolean and when it is defined as String and wr it is used in your code?

Comment: Ok. Can you share that piece of code as well

Comment: let loginOrRecovery;
        if(this.props.loginPage.login_form) {
            loginOrRecovery = <Login/>
        } else if(this.props.loginPage.password_recovery_form) {
            loginOrRecovery = <RecoverPassword/>
        }

Comment: this is in render, and after that I drew  either login form or recoverypassword form

Comment: login_form is from your Redux state which is a key of loginPage. So I don’t think prop type login_form applies to the login_form in loginPage object

Comment: no,there is no wornings :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html):

> When an invalid value is provided for a prop, a warning will be shown in the JavaScript console. For performance reasons, propTypes is only checked in development mode.

If you're running the project that is not in development mode, then you cannot see the warning.

See update below: <strike>Also, PropTypes doesn't throw an error but show warning. Be sure to check warning in the console. You might have selected to show error only.</strike>

And also, be sure to import the PropTypes from 'prop-types' to work with PropTypes:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

---

If the above thing is assured and you still don't see the warning in the console, then there's one probability you pass boolean value in string:

```
<LoginPage login_form="true" />
```

Or,

```
<LoginPage login_form={'true'} />
```

Be sure to pass boolean value like this:

```
<LoginPage login_form={true} />
```

Note: if you want to pass the true value, you may just pass the props like this:

```
<LoginPage login_form />
```

Now, having `login_form: PropTypes.string` will show you warning.

---

**Update:**

Though react doc says it will throw warning, I just verified that it actually throws an error without application hold. But the message is starting with `Warning:`. Thus, be sure to check **error** in the console not warning.

[image]

Or, you may be sure to check `default`.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. I am passing boolean true but it is still not working, also I am not passing like  <LoginPage login_form={true} />, I am using redux state. any ideas :? :/

Comment: props is to be passed in the component. I think you got something wrong with the prop types.

Comment: so, when I click button, I dispatch action like this.props.dispatch({type: "SHOW_LOGIN_FORM"}); and after that I set login_form as true, from reducer.

Comment: case types.SHOW_LOGIN_FORM:
            return { login_form: true , password_recovery_form: false };

Comment: and then pass the props in the component `<LoginPage login_form={this.props.reducervalue} />`. is this happening?

Comment: you were right, my mistake was: I was trying to create proptype in different container. thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

React will automatically check the propTypes you set on the component and show [warning] in the console.
But if you are using PropTypes without React then you can manually call PropTypes.checkPropTypes so in your case.

```
const myPropTypes = {
  login_form: PropTypes.string,
  // ... define your prop validations
};

const props = {
  login_form: true, // not valid
};

PropTypes.checkPropTypes(myPropTypes, props, 'prop', 'LoginPage');
```

Comment: ok, this works, but one thing I can't understand. should I asign custom values in props, I mean if login_form is boolean I should write login_form: true and if it is string login_form: 'any custom string' and so on.. :?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React ,{ Component }from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Person extends Component {
    render(){
        console.log('person.js-rendering- child components');
        return (
            <div classes="person">
                <p onClick={this.props.personClick}>I am {this.props.name} and I am  {this.props.age} years old</p>
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                <input type="text" onChange={ this.props.personChange } id='inputName' value={ this.props.name } />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
Person.propTypes={
    personClick:PropTypes.func,
    children:PropTypes.func,
    personChange:PropTypes.func,
    name:PropTypes.string,
    age:PropTypes.number
}
export default Person;
```