# Handling optional function props - defaultProps or check prop exists?

Tags: reactjs

If I want to have a function prop to be optional on a component, inside the component, is it better practice to use `defaultProps` to assign a `noop` function or should I check throughout the component if the function exists or not?

e.g. an optional `onChange` function -

```
<Input />
```

inside `Input.js`

```
if(this.props.onChange){
   this.props.onChange(e)
}
```

v.s.

```
defaultProps = {
   onChange: () => {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The props are required or optional and they are defined in the [prop types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Example:

```
Input.PropTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func, // optional
  onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // required
  exampleProps: 'my example'
}
```

You don't need to pass a noop function in the defaultProps. The default props is used if you need to initialize the props even if the user doesn't provide in the component. In the above example the prop `exampleProps` will be received in the `Input` component if user doesn't provide the `exampleProps`, else `Input` component will get/set the `exampleProps` from provided `Input` props `exampleProps`.

For eg.:

```
<Input exampleProps={'my new props'} />
```

Input sets exampleProps to `my new props`.

```
<Input />
```

Input sets exampleProps to `my example`.

---

As per your requirement, you don't need to set noop function but prop types set its type to be function `func`, and if you pass incorrect types, it will throw you an error stating a warning message.

```
<Input onChange={123} />
{/* will throw you an error */}
```

Optionally, you may also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216779/prop-types-not-working-in-react-application/52217307#52217307) for a little more info.

Comment: thanks for the input - though I think you have misunderstood my question, I have some code in `Input` to call `this.props.onChange` but if `onChange` is optional and it isn't supplied, I would get a `this.props.onChange is not a function` - What is the best way to avoid this?  To create a defaultProps entry as a `noop` function or do a truthy check to see if the function exists? e.g. `if(this.props.onChange)...`

Comment: No. You won't get such error if you use prop types. Have you tried?